# Why will my string only work when I put it in manually?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, contenteditable

Here is the exact string that is stored in the db:

```
@blog_post.content = "<p><img src=\"http://localhost:3000/assets/sa_clubbing_logo.png\" alt=\"Sa_clubbing_logo\"><div><b>An image</b></div><div><b><br></b></div><div><b>Another image</b></div><div><b><img src=\"http://localhost:3000/assets/sa_clubbing_logo.png\" alt=\"Sa_clubbing_logo\"><br></b></div></p>"
```

as you can see. It is made up of a few images and some bold text.

Ok, so I have html saved in the db. I am trying to append the html to a content editable div (my rich text editor) like this.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){  

  $('#rte').append("<%= @blog_post.content %>");

  });
```

It is showing up in my content editable div, but as actual text. I want it to be rendered as html so the images are actually showing. It seems like the html that is being appended is this:

```
<p>&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src="http://localhost:3000/assets/sa_clubbing_logo.png" alt="Sa_clubbing_logo"&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;b&gt;An image&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;b&gt;Another image&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;img src="http://localhost:3000/assets/sa_clubbing_logo.png" alt="Sa_clubbing_logo"&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</p>
```

So I tried putting the string into the append method manually and I got exactly what I wanted:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){  

  $('#rte').append("<p><img src=\"http://localhost:3000/assets/sa_clubbing_logo.png\" alt=\"Sa_clubbing_logo\"><div><b>An image</b></div><div><b><br></b></div><div><b>Another image</b></div><div><b><img src=\"http://localhost:3000/assets/sa_clubbing_logo.png\" alt=\"Sa_clubbing_logo\"><br></b></div></p>");

  });
```

The html being appended here is this:

```
<p><img src="http://localhost:3000/assets/sa_clubbing_logo.png" alt="Sa_clubbing_logo"></p><div><b>An image</b></div><div><b><br></b></div><div><b>Another image</b></div><div><b><img src="http://localhost:3000/assets/sa_clubbing_logo.png" alt="Sa_clubbing_logo"><br></b></div><p></p>
```

The images are showing up in my editor just the way I imagined they should.

Why does this work when I insert the string manually, but not when I use `<%= @blog_posts.content %>` ?

I must be missing some sort of formatting issue here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace:

```
<%= @blog_post.content %>
```

With:

```
<%=raw @blog_post.content %>
```

Or:

```
<%== @blog_post.content %>
```

Or even:

```
<%= @blog_post.content.html_safe %>
```

Explanation:

Rails protects you by default so you have to tell when you consider html safe.

Comment: WARNING: If you allow posting of html into your database from anyone but yourself, you open yourself up to XSS attacks!  There's a very good reason why rails has this functionality, be sure you understand why before bypassing it like this!

Comment: The user will not be able to type raw html into the form. The input is going into a rich text editor and the html that is being stored in the db is being generated. If the user types <script> it will be saved in the db as &lt;script&gt; . I don't know much about security. Is there still a hole here? I can't imagine how they could type the html in manually.